# RX stream of start and stop events with late subscription

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rx-py

I'm trying to make a subject of start and stop events where late subscribers only receive the outstanding start events. ie. those that haven't had a corresponding stop event.

Here's some RxPY code:

```py
from rx.subjects import ReplaySubject

start = ReplaySubject()

start.subscribe(lambda x: print("subscriber1: " + str(x)))

start.on_next(("a", "start"))
start.on_next(("b", "start"))
start.on_next(("b", "stop"))

start.subscribe(lambda x: print("subscriber2: " + str(x)))

start.on_next(("c", "start"))
```

This gives the output:

```
subscriber1: ('a', 'start')
subscriber1: ('b', 'start')
subscriber1: ('b', 'stop')
subscriber2: ('a', 'start')
subscriber2: ('b', 'start')
subscriber2: ('b', 'stop')
subscriber1: ('c', 'start')
subscriber2: ('c', 'start')
```

Whereas I would like:

```
subscriber1: ('a', 'start')
subscriber1: ('b', 'start')
subscriber1: ('b', 'stop')
subscriber2: ('a', 'start')
subscriber1: ('c', 'start')
subscriber2: ('c', 'start')
```

I think something like the scan operator is required but can't quite put it together. Any ideas gratefully received :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to use side effects off the main stream to update a dictionary and merge in the unfinished events to new subscribers.

```py
class EventObserver(Observer):
  def __init__(self):
    self.cached_events = set()
    self.mirror = Subject() # re-emits all values

  on_next(self, value):
    self.mirror.next(value) # stream to late observers
    if(value[1] == 'stop'):
      try:
        self.cached_events.remove(value[0])
      except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
      self.cached_events.add(value[0])

  on_error(self, e):
    self.mirror.error(e) # + other error logic

  on_completed(self):
    self.mirror.complete() # + other completion logic

  late_subscribe(self, subscriber):
    return Observable.merge(
      Observable.from(list(self.cached_events)),
      self.mirror
    ).subscribe(subscriber)
```

Used as follows:

```py
event_observer = EventObserver()
events$.subscribe(event_observer)

# late subscription:
event_observer.late_subscribe(...)
```

The rest of the answer explains why you'll probably prefer this over a reactive approach.

---

#### Reactive approach:

Here's the simplest solution I could think of, if you don't mind your late subscribers waiting until the next event. As you can see, it's not the prettiest.

```py
pub_events$ = events$.publish(); # in case your events$ aren't hot
replay_events$ = pub_events$.replay();

# late subscription:
replay_events$.window(events$.take(1))
              .scan(lambda is_first, o: 
                      o.reduce(lambda D, x: D.update({ x[0]: x[1] == 'stop' }) or D, {})
                       .flatMap(lambda D: Observable.from([ k for k, v in D.items() if v == False ]))
                      if is_first == True else o,
                    True)
              .flatMap(lambda o: o)
```

The goal is to start the late subscription with a filtered list of unfinished events built from a cache of all prior events. The biggest barrier is that `ReplaySubject` does not differentiate these cached events from new ones. The first step to tackle this above is to `window` on the next event, expecting `ReplaySubject` to emit the cached events before then. Since your requirement sounds like an optimization rather than correctness, the race condition here may not be a big deal.

There are at most two windows: one of the cached events, and one of the new events (if there are any), so `scan` exploits Python type weakness a bit to check which window we're in. If it's the cached events, we build a dictionary of event keys → whether or not that event is "stopped". The last step is to inject the unstopped values back into the stream with a `flatMap`.